# GIMP photo editor will not install on 64 bit laptop

Tags: windows-7, gimp

I have an ASUS P53E-XH31 with Windows 7 Pro 64-bit Operating System loaded. Whenever I try to load GIMP photo editor I get the following message: C:\Users\Jimmie\Downloads\gimp-2.8.2-setup-1.exe is not a valid Win32 application. I have tried saving/loading GIMP to other locations but I am always blocked with an Administrator permission required message. I read on the internet others are loading and using GIMP with Win7 64 bit. I am stumbling around at this time as I do not have a lot of computer experience. Anyone got any idea what my real issue is here other than not knowing what to do?

Comment: I assume you don't have admin access?

Answer (score 1):

My gut feelings is that even though you have a 64 bit processor, you have a 32 bit version of Windows 7 installed.

Right click "My Computer" and select "Properties."  Under the System heading, look at "System Type."  What does it say?  Im betting it says 32 bit operating system, not 64.

The reason I say this is your error message: `C:\Users\Jimmie\Downloads\gimp-2.8.2-setup-1.exe is not a valid Win32 application` The clue is "Win32" application.

Try downloading the 32 bit version of Gimp, and see if it installs...  if it does, theres your answer.

Of course, all this is assuming you have Administrator privileges.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong end of the gun: a) there is only 1 version of gimp through the "download" link 2) if it wasn't compatible it would still load up and then spit an error.  So it may be true that they only have a 32bit system, but it shouldn't affect this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me on the GIMP Download page that there is only one option, so it sounds like you have an incomplete download on your hands (especially since it won't even start to try to install).

Check the MD5 of your download, according to GIMP.org it should be

```
64cb169bb7cfac115805b686cb1b2141
```

If that doesn't match you have a corrupted download and you'll need to try again.

You can check your md5 with [WinMD5Free](http://www.winmd5.com/).

**Note:** As others have noted, you will need to have admin rights to install anything.